# Xamarin Test Recorder with Physical Device - instruments failed to start the app

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-test-cloud

I have been able to successfully use Xamarin Test Recorder to generate test scripts using the `iOS and Android simulators`, however, when I try to use a physical device, The "Select App" dropdown doesn't show any apps that have been installed on the device.

Since the "Select App" drop down doesn't show any options, after I selected the device, I tried specifying the IPA that is built out in the bin folder as the app to launch.

Looking at the output logs in the Test Recorder, this seemed to work fine, as it was able to resign and reinstall the app to the device, however, when it attempts to launch the app I get an "`instruments failed to start the app`" message.

How can I use a physical device with Xamarin Test Recorder?

Comment: What version of Xamarin Test Recorder are you using?